# OpenFileDialog filter keeps showing extensions

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

Run `mspaint.exe` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. The file extension filter shown has this special entry "All Picture Files". Now, how do I create such a filter in `WPF`? (I'm quite sure I've managed to do this in `Win32` back in the days.)

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.DefaultExt = ".tif";
dlg.Filter =
    "All Picture Files|*.bmp;*.dib;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif;*.tif;*.tiff;*.png|" +
    "All Files|*.*";

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

The code above works, but it yields these bloated filter *labels*:

`All Picture Files (*.bmp;*.dib;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif;*.tif;*.tiff;*.png)`

`All Files (*.*)`

**I didn't ask for those parentheses, so where do they come from?!**

### EDIT

Apparently, depending on the Windows option to hide the extension on known file types (in the Windows Explorer folder settings), the extensions are automatically added or not. I believe WPF does the right thing here!

Comment: Speak of which, I would like to know how to avoid that bloated string myself